# Lack of any*() static methods in Mockito 1. How to replace them reasonably?

Tags: java, mockito

I have following jar in my project and I haven't seen any problems up to now:

```
mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
```

Due to project maturity I am not able to shift to newer Mockito version.

I am lacking any*() methods that I need: these are anyObject() and anyString(). These are static methods of Mockito 2.2.7 API. Are they missing in 1.10 version and subversions.

Source:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyList()

How can I replace those methods - maybe there had been present some deprecated methods I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
any(Object.class);
any(String.class);
```

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)

Since `Mockito` extends `Matchers` you can get all the matchers with:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*
```

... which is the style recommended by Mockito.

Comment: Thank you can you provide the source package also to your answer, please?

Comment: I can assume its static member of `Mockito`

Comment: Yes it is - in order to import it one has to type import static org.mockito.Matchers.any has to be used. Thank you. I upvote and click approval tick.